# SP16 - How to hide time span in SharePoint calendar without CSS

Tags: sharepoint-server, list-view, 2016, sharepoint-calendar

I want to **remove/hide** time in calendar view, how to do this without CSS?
[image]
How to access element and  format his data before rendering the calendar view?

I use this function to disable drag/drop and Add new element

```
 ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(fixupCalendar, 'SP.UI.ApplicationPages.Calendar.js');
    function fixupCalendar(){                   
      var calendarCreate = SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarContainerFactory.create;
      SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarContainerFactory.create = function(elem, cctx, viewType, date, startupData) {
        cctx.canUserCreateItem = false;
        cctx.aM12String= "";

        if(cctx.dataSources && cctx.dataSources instanceof Array && cctx.dataSources.length > 0){
            for(var i = 0; i < cctx.dataSources.length; i++){
              cctx.dataSources[i].disableDrag = true; //
             }
            calendarCreate(elem, cctx, viewType, date, startupData);
        }
}
```

Can I format the data in a similar way before it is rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I check all the attributes related to time in SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarContainerFactory.create function and there is not attribute for the time.

I suppose that you need to use CSS to hide the time.

```
.ms-acal-time{display:none;}
```

Or using the following the hide the time after the calendar is rendered:

```
setTimeout(hidetimes, 3000);
function hidetimes(){ 
var timesToHide = document.getElementsByClassName("ms-acal-time");
for(var i = 0; i < timesToHide.length; i++)
    {
       timesToHide[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```